# same error generated again and again every minutes in /var/log/syslog

Tags: logs

```
Apr 14 02:04:26 flippingbits gnome-session[4943]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:5638): WARNING **: recent-manager-provider.vala:132: Desktop file for "file:///home/edward/Downloads/delete/wall_cars_lamborghini_aventador_red_front_view_1920x1200_26192.jpg" was not found, exec: google-chrome-stable, mime_type: image/jpeg
```

---

```
Apr 14 02:02:18 flippingbits kernel: [48165.560619] [drm:i915_gem_context_create_ioctl] HW context 9 created
```

These two error is generated in my `/var/log/syslog` file every minute 7-8 times. Why? How can I solve this?

copy of `syslog` file at the time of writing question is [here](http://sprunge.us/bUaQ)

Answer (score 1):

The first one looks like it may be because you customized chrome to use the image file shown in the message. The second one is just informational.